# Replacing data in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, regex, google-sheets-dates

I am new to coding! I have data in Sheet 1 of a Larger Spreadsheet that looks like this

```
25.06.18
```

and wish to change it to look like

```
26/06/18
```

I have tried to write a macro:

```
function Dated() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("ac7:ag24");
  var to_replace = ".";
  var replace_with = "/";
  replaceInSheet(sheet,range, to_replace, replace_with);
 };
```

However, I get an error:

> ReferenceError: "replaceInSheet" is not defined.

It is possibly quite simple but cannot solve it!

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Welcome. `replaceInSheet` isn't a built-in Google Apps Script function, it should be declared somewhere. Have you wrote that function?

Answer (score -1):

- you can use internal functions like:

  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(AC7:AG24, ".", "/"))
  ```

  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(AC7:AG24, ".", "/"))
  ```
- or even internal formatting:

  [image: 0]

Comment: This doesn't replace the data in place, this adds a new column.